# Group by intersecting vectors

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, intersection

Consider this `tibble`:

```r
tibble(id = list(c(1, 2), c(3, 4, 7), c(3, 5), 10, c(5, 6)))

  id       
  <list>   
1 <dbl [2]>
2 <dbl [3]>
3 <dbl [2]>
4 <dbl [1]>
5 <dbl [2]>
```

I'd like to group `id` if one or more value in one row is also in another row. Here, the first row is `1 2` and neither 1 nor 2 appear in other rows, it is then the only one assigned `group == 1`. Same with row 4. Row 2, 3 and 5 share digit 3 (for row 2 and 3) and digit 5 (row 3 and 5), they are then all assigned to the same group.

Expected output:

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  id        group
  <list>    <dbl>
1 <dbl [2]>     1
2 <dbl [3]>     2
3 <dbl [2]>     2
4 <dbl [1]>     3
5 <dbl [2]>     2
```

Any ideas on how to do this? maybe `igraph`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)

df %>%
  mutate(rn = paste0('node', row_number()))%>%
  left_join(unnest(., id) %>%
              graph_from_data_frame(dir = FALSE) %>% 
              components() %>%
              getElement('membership')%>%
              enframe('rn', 'group'))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  id        rn    group
  <list>    <chr> <dbl>
1 <dbl [2]> node1     1
2 <dbl [3]> node2     2
3 <dbl [2]> node3     2
4 <dbl [1]> node4     3
5 <dbl [2]> node5     2
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks! It's a shame that one has to make such a convoluted code for something that appear quite intuitive.

Comment: @Maël  might be intuitive to us but not to the computer. We need to do alot of computations. Also if this solves your problem consider closing the question by accepting the solution

Comment: @Maël thats fine. Although it seems quite impossible to get any answer shorter than this. I hope the code provided helps